# pandas resample frequency issue

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am facing an issue w.r.t pandas resample.
I have OHLC data of 1m frequency. I wish to convert this data into 5m frequency and calculate moving average of it.
Say I am taking moving average of 20 bars (of 5m each) then first I am loading 100bars (1m bar) to dataframe, convert it to 5m frequency using

```
conversion = {'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last', 'Volume': 'last'}

resample_high = df_high.resample('5T', closed='right',label='right').apply(conversion).dropna()
```

then calculate moving average of this new data frame. After 1 minute new 1m data bar will be available (live feed) and I will update the current data frame as 
1.) delete the 1st entry from data frame (total entry 99)
2.) add new entry to data frame (total entry 100)

again I will calculate the moving average and continue with above process till end of day.

The issue here is when I am creating resampled dataframe it starts from

```
xx:05:00
xx:10:00
xx:15:00
```

I am expecting the frame to start with first date index like say data is :-

```
4/8/2016 14:27,850.6,850.75,849.85,849.85,4667
4/8/2016 14:28,849.85,849.95,849.4,849.5,9933
4/8/2016 14:29,849.5,850,849.45,850,2720
4/8/2016 14:30,849.95,850.45,849.45,849.45,7795
4/8/2016 14:31,849.45,850.95,849.45,850.9,7143
```

5m resampling starts with

```
4/8/2016 14:30:00 XX XX XX XX
```

Due to this calculation of simple moving average is wrong each time as new entry is not being added to dataframe calculation.

Please let me know if anything is not clear, I will try to make it more elaborate.

Added code for resampling and calculation of SMA  (using TALIB module).

```
conversion    = {'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close':'last', 'Volume': 'last'}
order         = df_high.columns.tolist()
resample_high = df_high.resample('5T', closed='right',    label='right').apply(conversion).dropna()
df_h          = resample_high[order]
SMA_20        = talib.SMA(np.array(df_h['Close']), timeperiod=20)[19] }
```

Issue with conversion :-
My data is :-

```
04/08/16    10:32:00    843.9   844.1   843.8   843.8   3618
04/08/16    10:33:00    843.85  844     843.5   843.7   3590
04/08/16    10:34:00    843.6   843.8   843.25  843.55  3841
04/08/16    10:35:00    843.55  843.9   843.55  843.75  4012
04/08/16    10:36:00    843.75  844.2   843.75  843.85  5337
04/08/16    10:37:00    843.9   844.8   843.9   844.4   2978
04/08/16    10:38:00    844.4   844.75  844.4   844.6   2773
04/08/16    10:39:00    844.55  844.85  844.3   844.4   3887
```

After conversion I am getting :-

```
2016-04-08 10:35:00  843.90  844.10  843.25  843.75    4012
2016-04-08 10:35:00  843.85  844.00  843.25  843.75    4012
2016-04-08 10:35:00  843.60  843.90  843.25  843.75    4012
2016-04-08 10:35:00  843.55  843.90  843.55  843.75    4012
```

Comment: What code have you written for above?

Comment: Hi Merlin, I have added code which converts to 5m frequency and calculate SMA (TALIB library function).

Comment: I am noticing that even the conversion is not happening properly. Please see edit..section

Comment: Format your code with {}....  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Format your data as well, cant read it.

Comment: With conversion, what are you expecting to get

Comment: @ Merlin, I got your point. Thanks !! But I have basic doubt now.. when I say that resample "5min" that should mean that it should have 5bars in it. But in last bar the data is only for 1 bar ?